# "He helped write the program." Infinitive topic

Tags: grammar

I'm studying about Infinitive topic. The website tells me that some element in this sentence is dropped. I think the full sentence is "He helped me write the Program" but I don't understand the rule that is used to drop some element in the sentence.

Comment: Do you mean: I'm studying use of the infinitive? What website tells you that, please?

Comment: Sorry for my terrible English 555. Yes,that's right. and the website is http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000078.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructions involving the verb ***to help***, it's perfectly natural (but not *obligatory*) to "delete" the infinitive marker ***to*** before the relevant verb identifying the action for which assistance was provided...

> *He helped me [**to**] **write** the program*

---

There's more background on this use of ***to help*** [someone] [**to**] do something in the ELU question [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) (which was asked some years before this ELL site was created).

---

I'd be interested to know if anyone can come up with any alternative verbs instead of ***write*** above that would both make reasonable sense *and* either require or disallow the infinitive marker ***to***.

Comment: Is it possible to drop either "me" and "to" in the sentence?

Comment: Yes, you *could* omit ***me*** as well as or intead of ***to***. But that's not exactly the same as "deleting" the "**100% predictable**" repetition of ***to***, since the speaker might have meant, for example, *He helped **Mary** write the program*. In which case he *still* might not bother mentioning Mary by name, if that was obviously contextually what was meant, or if it was totally irrelevant who received assistance.